# Ошибка при извлечении значения из массива

Tags: php, json

PHP код

```
$arr = file_get_contents("../json/".$idv.".json");
    $arr = json_decode($arr);
    /*30 строка*/ $vname = $arr['vname'];
    $desc = $arr['desc'];
    $src = $arr['src'];
    $comments = $arr['comments'];
    $data = [
        'idv' => $idv,
        'date' => $date,
        'idp' => $idp,
        'vname' => $vname,
        'desc' => $desc,
        'src' => $src,
        'comments' => $comments
    ];
```

Ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скажите, каким способом нам узнать что у вас находится в файле `/json/".$idv.".json`? Вопрос требует дополнения.

Comment: Попробуйте так json_decode($arr, 1); И почитайте подробнее про json_decode, там много разных ключей. В частности второй аргумент = true преобразует объекты в ассоциативный массив

Comment: В файле - `{"vname":"Jss","src":"http:\/\/video.sibnet.ru\/shell.php?videoid=3291274","desc":"Jsjs","date":"2018-21-05 10:34:23"}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Второй аргумент функции `json_decode` равный `true` преобразует объекты в ассоциативный массив.

```
<?php
    $arr = '{"vname":"Jss","src":"http:\/\/video.sibnet.ru\/shell.php?videoid=3291274","desc":"Jsjs","date":"2018-21-05 10:34:23"}';
    $arr = json_decode($arr, true); // Ошибка была тут
    $vname = $arr['vname'];// 30 строка
    echo $vname; //Jss
?>
```

[Справка по json-decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: `bool $assoc = FALSE ` -не понимаю, зачем делать `int`, когда указано `bool`. Лишний каст, не так ли?

Comment: @And, пожалуйста, почитайте на досуге [Справка > Наша модель  > Будьте дружелюбными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: @And, исправил ответ для вас! Радуйтесь и наслаждайтесь! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Потому-что, обращаетесь к массиву, а конвертируете в объект.
Второй аргумент функции `json_decode` нужно выставить в `true`.

```
$arr = json_decode($arr, true);
$vname = $arr['vname'];
echo $vname; // Jss
```

В случае с объектом, нужно будет обращаться по `$arr->vname`.